# Move 3d models in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, public

In unity 3d, I've create an Empty GameObject that Instanciates a simple 3d model when i click with the mouse ( 3d model imported from blender).

I've written a simple script that moves the EmptyGameObject using

```
transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

But when i run the project, only the Empty Game Object moving but I need that the 3d model moving to x asix. How can i resolve this problem? Thanks for the help.

Moving script (putting on EmptyGameObject):

```
public float speed = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            speed += speed + 0.5f;

        }
    }
```

Script for instantiated objects:

```
   public GameObject model;
   public GameObject model1;


public int counter = 0;

    void Start(){
     model=  Instantiate(model, transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //spawn model
    }

    void Update(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        ChangeModel();
    }
    }


    void ChangeModel(){
    counter++;
            switch (counter) {

                case 1:
                    Destroy(model);
                    Destroy(model1);
                    model = (GameObject) Instantiate(model, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Destroy(model);
                    model1= (GameObject) Instantiate(model1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    counter =0;
                    break;


            }
    }
```

Comment: if the model is a child of your empty game object it will move with it

Comment: @BugFinder 
how can I set the model as a child by script?

Comment: You can either set parent, or do it as part of the instantiate..

Comment: Are you trying to move child object or your aim is just moving them together ?

Comment: @UgurTufekci yes i need to moving them together but now only the EmptyGameObject moving..

Comment: where are you using Instanciate?

Comment: @derHugo 
I have now posted my code (Using in the EmptyGameObject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general all you need to do is spawn the new objects always as **children** of this `EmptyGameObject`.  [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) therefore has an overload taking an additional parent `Transform` reference to spawn the prefab as child to.

As I understand the second script is also attached to the `EmptyGameObject` so your target parent is simply `transform` (the `Transform` component of the `GameObject` this script is attached to):

```
//spawn model as child of given Transform
model = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
```

Also note that a cast to `(GameObject)` is redundant since `Instantiate` anyway returns the type of the given prefab.

---

#### However

I do not really understand your usage of `model`, `model1` and `Instantiate` and `Destroy` here ...

What do you destroy the `model` for if you want to directly respawn it anyway?

In general I think you would be way better also performance wise spawning them both **once** and only activate and deactivate according models:

```
public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject prefab1;

void Start()
{
    model =  Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
    model1 = Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);

    model1.SetActive(false);
}

void ChangeModel()
{
    counter = (counter + 1) % 2;

    model.SetActive(counter == 0);
    model1.SetActive(counter == 1);
}
```

That's it. If you simply already place the two prefabs into the `EmptyGameObject` right from the beginning you don't need the `Instantiate` at all ...

And btw in case you only have two states anyway instead of a counter you could also use a simple `bool` here:

```
bool isModel1;

private void ChangeModel()
{
    isModel1 = !isModel1;

    model.SetActive(!isModel1);
    model1.SetActive(isModel1);
}
```

---

And finally note that from your movement script:

```
speed += speed + 0.5f;
```

this results in

```
speed = speed + speed + 0.5f;
```

but I guess what you rather want is

```
speed += 0.5f;
```

which results in

```
speed = speed + 0.5f;
```

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful :)